# scandir error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Can anyone help me out with this code? I can't seem to get it to work!

```
<?php
$file = scandir("../");

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if(is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'images') {
        $folders++; // Counter
    } elseif(is_file($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php') {
        $total++; // Counter
    }
}

echo "$folders folders · $total files";
?>
```

And the error I get is:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Typo: `$file = scandir("../");` should be `$files = ...` -1 for lack of basic debugging efforts. Also, you don't initialize $folders, nor $total

Comment: Still doesn't work as `$files`

Comment: Re-check your variable names.  If `$files` is the array generated by `scandir()`, then your `foreach` needs to step through that, setting `$file` to each value of the array.  To see if the output of `scandir()` is failing, add a `print_r($files);` before your `foreach`.

Comment: it works with the `print_r($files);`

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of all your codes always helps

Well, if you are getting foreach error but no `Undefined variable: files` one - it seems you are doing something evil on the `$files` variable between scandir and a loop.

Or you are just fooling everyone running some other code, not one posted here.

Comment: I get these errors when I do that: `Undefined variable: folders` and `Undefined variable: total`

Comment: Please think for a moment at your code, and imagine there is not SO out there, nor google: how would you solve your problem? Undefined variable? Define it first! (in this case you use a counter, but you don't initialize it)

Comment: @FlameTrap it is all right if you are still getting your foreach error.

Comment: I have the undefined variable errors but not the foreach error anymore